# Expression evaluation mechanism of Python

Tags: python, expression, evaluation

I used to believe for the Python expression `f(g)(x)`, the evaluation process is:

1. Evaluate `f(g)`, return function `h`;
2. Evaluate `h(x)`, return the final result.

But the code below shows this is not true:

```
def double(x):
    return 2 * x

def double_or_zero(f):
    def f_or_zero(x):
        if x > 0:
            return f(x)
        else:
            return -999
    return f_or_zero

print(double_or_zero(double)(3))
print(double_or_zero(double)(-3))
```

When the *first* part (if it exists) `double_or_zero(double)` is evaluated, it can "see" the parameter (`3` and `-3`) in the *next* step,
which shows the from-left-to-right evaluation model is not true.

So what is the expression evaluation mechanism for Python (2.x and 3.x)?

## Update

Thanks to Bi Rico's answer, Python evaluates expression from left to right strictly. Hope the code below can make it more clear:

```
def double(x):
    return 2 * x

def f_or_zero(this_f):
    def this_f_or_zero(x):
        print('I am running with x = %s' % x)
        if x > 0:
            return this_f(x)
        else:
            return -999
    print('I am created: %s' % this_f_or_zero)
    return this_f_or_zero

double_or_zero = f_or_zero(double)
print(double_or_zero(3))
print(double_or_zero(-3))
```

Run it:

```
$ python demo.py
I am created: <function this_f_or_zero at 0x7f9f53786500>
I am running with x = 3
6
I am running with x = -3
-999
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the problem.  how does the code below show that this is not true?  `double_or_zero(double)` returns a function that takes a parameter (`h(x)`) and depending on that parameter (`x`) either returns `double(x)` or `-999`...

Comment: @mgilson If Python interpreter parses `double_or_zero(double)(3)` from left to right strictly, it should have no idea about what the next part (`3`) is, because `3` is out of the current evaluation scope(`double_or_zero(double)`).

Comment: This behavior is exactly what I would expect if evaluation order is from left-to-right. f(g) returns a function h, which itself takes a parameter, in your example 3 or -3, and gives the corresponding output depending on the sign.  It is working exactly as you describe in points 1 and 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you think that python can see the parameter when the first part is evaluated, it can't. This example might make what's happening more clear. Your example works the same way.

```
def double(x):
    return 2 * x

def f_or_zero(this_f):
    def this_f_or_zero(x):
        if x > 0:
            return this_f(x)
        else:
            return 0
    return this_f_or_zero


double_or_zero = f_or_zero(double)
print(double_or_zero(3))
print(double_or_zero(-3))
```

`double_or_zero` is a function that behaves (mostly) like any other python function. It just so happens that this function is created dynamically and returned by a call to another function.